# DateTime conversion during asynchronous process

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asynchronous

i am doing set of process as Asynchronous in C#. When i am trying to convert the string ("12/02/2015") to datetime type it is showing the error called String is not in the correct format to convert. But the same code worked before making as asynchronous process.

```
DateTime.Parse("12/02/2015 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Maybe _asynchronous process_ changed the `CurrentCulture` settings? What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way? Show working code as well. But I don't think the process _type_ can change the behaviour of `DateTime.Parse` for your string.

Comment: You can try `ParseExact` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a new thread, by default its locale will be set to the operating system's default locale. It will *not* necessarily be set to the culture selected in Windows Regional Settings.

You can fix this by adding the following line of code to the beginning of your thread function:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Alternatively, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` and specify exactly which format you want to parse, for example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/2015 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that "/" and ":" characters in the format string are not verbatim characters; they specify the date and time separators respectively. They happen to map to the same characters in the invariant culture, but they may map to different characters in other cultures.

To specify that exactly those "/" and ":" characters should be used, you have to escape them like so:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/2015 00:00:00", "dd\\/MM\\/yyyy HH\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: But still im getting the same error. DateTime appDate = DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/2015 00:00:00", 
                "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Nathiya Have a look at the format string you're using, and then look at the one I used. They are not the same. You didn't specify the "HH:mm:ss" bit.